# Alignment issues while printing Avery 5160 labels

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to print bunch of data here is my css for `Avery 5160 labels`

```css
body {
    width: 8.27in;
    margin: 0in .2in;
}
.label {
    /* Avery 5160 labels */
    width: 3.24016in; /* plus .6 inches from padding */
    height: 1.381in; /* plus .125 inches from padding */
    padding: .125in 0 .05in .3in;
    margin-right: .515in; /* the gutter */

    float: left;

    /* text-align: center; */
    overflow: hidden;

    outline: 1px dotted;  /*outline doesn't occupy space like border does */
}
```

The problem is if i print 16 labels i.e 1 page it comes out nicely. But if it goes to page 2 bottom labels kind of crops and messes page 2.

my test code in php

```php
$max = 15; // if max then 15 :/ i cri
 $str1 = "<b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958";
for ($i=0; $i <= 16; $i++) { 
 echo'<div class="label">'. $str1.'</div>';
}
```

script for printing

```js
var t;
function prt()
{
    clearTimeout(t);
    window.print();
}
t=setTimeout("prt()",1000);
```

Attaching SS [image: Attaching SS]

Attaching full source [Source](http://pastebin.com/kUbPixPz)

Comment: Did you have this issue in every browser?

Comment: I have made many bad experiences with label printing in browsers. The different Browser's print the labels very different. At the end I had to use a PDF.

Comment: Hi Bender, I recently faced same type of problem with cheque printing, now that was fixed by changing margin - padding settings.
Can you provide a online link of your code, so I can try for a solution for you.

Comment: @om_ attached pastbin full code , all you need to do is copy-past and run

Comment: @Magu yes all browsers,  i don't think its browser issue

Answer (score 1):

On my preview it looks difference if I print. I think this has to do with the margin of the printer.

Anyway, I change your `float:left;` to `display:inline-block` and add a page break after 14 elements. Does this work for you?

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Artpro</title>
<style>
body {
    width: 8.27in;
    margin: 0in .2in;
}
.label {
    /* Avery 5160 labels */
    width: 3.24016in; /* plus .6 inches from padding */
    height: 1.381in; /* plus .125 inches from padding */
    padding: .125in 0 .05in .3in;
    margin-right: .515in; /* the gutter */

    display: inline-block;

    /*text-align: center;*/
    overflow: hidden;

    outline: 1px dotted;  /*outline doesn't occupy space like border does */
}
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
</style>

<script>
    var t;
    function prt()
    {
        clearTimeout(t);
        window.print();
    }
    t=setTimeout("prt()",1000);
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
    <div class="label"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>

    <div class="label page-break"><b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have add a div out side of your loop, which create 14 labels on each pages.

Here is edited PHP code:

```php
$max = 15; // if max then 15 :/ i cri
$str1 = "<b>Title </b></br>Fname Lname</br>Media Type</br>200x500 cm</br>1958";
for ($n=0; $n < 22; $n++) {
echo '<div class="a4sized">';
for ($i=0; $i < 14; $i++) {
    echo'<div class="label">'. $str1.'</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
}
```

and CSS for new added div:

```css
.a4sized {
    background:#ff0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:11.69in;
}
```

I checked it on google crome with these settings:
Paper Size : A4, 
Margins : none

[image]